# fetching image using axios and use it as a background-image

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a dashboard component and I want fetch any image using axios, like from google and I want to set it as a background image for my component.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Dashboard extends React.Component {

    state = {
        bgImg: null
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdnilsolutions.
                    com%2Fdnil%2Findex.php%2Fabout-us%2F&psig=AOvVaw3DzPtJ_KH93oUH
                    IDDMBFup&ust=1586330645652000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjR
                    xqFwoTCKjVi6vk1egCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAN`)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({bgImg: response.data});
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    render() {
        return <div>{this.state.bgImg}</div>;
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have used axios.get to fetch a google image and tried to store in the state.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `{ responseType:"arraybuffer" }` argument to the get request in axios and convert the response to Base64:

```
axios.get(`https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-line-vol-1-1/52/blub__idea__solution__creative__process__design__education-512.png`, { responseType:"arraybuffer" })
  .then(response => {
    const image = btoa(
    new Uint8Array(response.data)
      .reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '')
    );
     const imageBase64 = `data:${response.headers['content-type'].toLowerCase()};base64,${image}`;
    this.setState({bgImg: imageBase64});
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

and use inline styles for setting background:

```
<div 
  className={"div-with-bg"}
  style={{backgroundImage:`url(${this.state.bgImg})`}}>
</div>
```

working example here on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8do2j0pc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Inline Style` to put image that you fetch in background of a `div`

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {

state = {
    bgImg: null
}
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdnilsolutions.
                com%2Fdnil%2Findex.php%2Fabout-us%2F&psig=AOvVaw3DzPtJ_KH93oUH
                IDDMBFup&ust=1586330645652000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjR
                xqFwoTCKjVi6vk1egCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAN`)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({bgImg: response.data});
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
}

render() {
    return <div style={{backgroundImage:`url(${this.state.bgImg})`}}></div>;
 }
}

export default Dashboard;
```